# Почему в этом предложении есть запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Но каждому в своё время, Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст.

Comment: А откуда это предложение? Кто автор?

Comment: Цитата из фильма "Господин никто".

Comment: Понятнее не стало. Этот фильм: [Господин Никто](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Господин_Никто_(фильм,_2009))? Он же на английском, как в нём может быть *письменная* цитата на русском языке?

Comment: Что?? Но его же перевели, ХАХХАХАХАХАХАХАХХА.Иначе многие фильмы и были на английском.. Там все на русском, не только цитата "Пока мы ещё не родились, мы знаем всё. Всё, что случится. Но каждому в своё время, Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст. И оставляют на верхней губе отметину. Это значит, что помеченный всё забывает." Можете загуглить, тогда, наверное, поймёте..

Comment: В любом случае вопрос некорректный, — там могло быть и тире, и точка, и тчк с зпт: автору понадобилась пауза — возникла запятая. Имеет право. Только он знает, зачем она.

Comment: Я не знала, что там пауза . И почему знает только он? Я то думала, запятая здесь обязательна.. Мне показалось, что ее здесь не должно  быть. Ладно, спасибо.

Comment: в любом случае сотрудники будут работать удалённо. Разве можно поставить запятую, сказав, что нужна была пауза? После "в любом случае" . По моему, это не будет правильно. Вот я и спросила, нужна ли там, ведь в похожих предложениях запятые не ставились.

Comment: *Вот я и спросила, нужна ли там,...* - вы спросили "почему в этом предложении есть запятая" - это несколько другой вопрос, чем "нужна ли здесь запятая" :) Можете, кстати, отредактировать ваш заголовок и сам вопрос, кликнув по  ссылке [Править](https://rus.stackexchange.com/posts/463436/edit). Будет больше шансов получить грамотный ответ. Я так понимаю, текст вы нашли на каком-то из многочисленных сайтов вроде этого: [цитата](https://citaty.info/quote/411585)? Безымянный автор записал несколько фраз из фильма на слух. Да, скорее всего этой запятой он решил обозначить паузу. Я считаю это ...

Comment: ... неправильным, но я никогда не считал себя знатоком нюансов пунктуации. Хорошо бы кто-нибудь более разбирающийся в правилах прокомментировал. Есть ещё такая мысль - если у вас есть этот фильм с русскими субтитрами, попробуйте посмотреть, как этот же текст передан в субтитрах. (О, а автор-то не совсем безымянный: "Добавила Алёнa 04.03.17 в 20:13"). ))

Comment: Нет, не безымянный.  Фильм то на русском, цитату никто не переводил, только фильм. И какая разница, как я задала вопрос, если ответ я получу один?  Тут просто объяснят, почему здесь запятая.  Если я спрошу, нужна ли здесь запятая, мне же не ответят одним словом. Они   так же ответят на вопрос. Поэтому ничего редактировать не надо, я именно так задавала вопросы, а получала тот ответ, который мне нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Английский язык:
*When it's your time, the angels of Oblivion place a finger on your mouth.*

Итальянский:
*Quando viene il tuo momento, gli angeli dell'Oblio ti posano un dito sulla bocca.*

*When* (англ.) — когда.
Я бы перевела так:
Когда приходит твое время, Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст.

В том переводе, который представлен Вами, запятая, естественно, **не нужна**. Она просто "автоматом" перекочевала из английского варианта в русский перевод.
**Но каждому в своё время Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст.**

Не возбраняется, конечно же, "поиграть" с пунктуацией — но для этого нужно знать контекст (к сожалению, я его не знаю). Возможные варианты:
Но — каждому в своё время Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст.
Но каждому, в своё время, Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст.
Но каждому — в своё время — Ангелы Забвения кладут на губы перст.